# MCMC simulations in R for a simple poisson model

Tags: r, markov-chain-montecarlo

I would like to put together my own R function for MCMC simulations rather than using a R package or Winbugs. This is purely to ensure I understand what is going on.

I have used the R Nimble package to construct a very simple model and to run the simulations.

The model code is as follows and from what I can see has ran successfully:

```
library(nimble)
ModelCode <- nimbleCode({ 
  for (i in 1:N){
  theta[i] ~ dgamma(alpha,beta) 
  lambda[i] <- theta[i]*t[i] 
  x[i] ~ dpois(lambda[i])
}
  alpha ~ dunif(0.0,100.0)
  beta ~ dunif(0.0,100.0)
})
Consts <- list(N = 10, t = c(15,12,8,8,6,5,5,4,4,3)) 
Data <- list(x = c(4,40,0,10,14,31,2,4,13,4))
Initial <- list(alpha = 99, beta = 99, theta = rep(0.1, Consts$N))
mcmc.out <- nimbleMCMC(code = ModelCode, constants = Consts, data = Data, inits = Initial, 
                       nchains = 2, niter = 2000, summary = TRUE, WAIC = TRUE, 
                       monitors = c('alpha','beta','lambda'))
```

Using this R Nimble package I have been able to obtain summary statistics from the posterior distribution as needed. However, as this is a simple model I wanted to put together an R function that does this from scratch in order to understand more fully what is going on.

There are some simple examples of the metropolis Hastings algorithm online that I am looking at but it is not clear to me how to expand these for two initial unknowns (alpha and beta) as per the model above. Some code for sampling an exponential distribution is shown below.

```
log_exp_target = function(x){
  return(dexp(x,rate=1, log=TRUE))
}

easyMCMC = function(log_target, niter, startval, proposalsd){
  x = rep(0,niter)
  x[1] = startval     
  for(i in 2:niter){
    currentx = x[i-1]
    proposedx = rnorm(1,mean=currentx,sd=proposalsd) 
    A = exp(log_target(proposedx) - log_target(currentx))
    if(runif(1)<A){
      x[i] = proposedx       # accept move with probabily min(1,A)
    } else {
      x[i] = currentx        # otherwise "reject" move, and stay where we are
    }
  }
  return(x)
}
```

I will continue reading but any code for this would be gratefully received.

Comment: Could you expand on the conceptual reasons for which you are uncertain with writing a Metropolis-Hastings (?) algorithm for this hierarchical Poisson model? (This model is not "very simple" as it involves a dimension 12 parameter.) Otherwise, this sounds like a homework.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way, although not necessarily the best, is just to loop over the  parameters at each iteration.  In this version, `startval` and `proposalsd` are vectors of length equal to the number of parameters:

```
       easyMCMC = function(log_target, niter, startval, proposalsd){
          nparms = length(startval)
          x = matrix(0,niter,nparms)
          x[1,] = startval     
          for (i in 2:niter){
            proposedx = currentx = x[i-1,]
            for (j in 1:nparms) {
              proposedx[j] = rnorm(1,mean=currentx[j],sd=proposalsd[j]) 
              A = exp(log_target(proposedx) - log_target(currentx))
              if (runif(1)<A){
                currentx[j] = proposedx[j] # accept the proposal if don't reject 
              } else {
                proposedx[j] = currentx[j] # undo the proposal if reject
              }
            }
            x[i,] = currentx
          }
          return(x)
        }
```

I have tried to adhere to your code as closely as possible, however, some improvements are there to be had; for example, at the end of each iteration, `proposedx` equals `currentx` equals `x[i-1,]`, so that assignment doesn't need to happen at the top of the iteration loop as long as `proposedx` and `currentx` are initialized outside the loop.